# using default iOS camera button as a UIButton

Tags: ios, camera

I am a newbie at iOS development so please be kind.

I want to use the default camera button as a UIButton. (I want the camera button to be displayed against a field in my form and want to use the default graphic because users are familiar with it)
I don't see any option to insert it as a simple UIButton, I don't want it in the toolbar.

If it's not possible to include it this way, can I use it's image as UIButton? Or it can cause any objection in the app review?

[image]

Comment: do you mean home screen icon or do you mean the little white camera graphic?

Comment: you have to make your own I'm afraid, it's not accessible by simple means to use the camera icon asset.

Comment: The little white camera graphic which appears when the identifier of a bar item is set to "camera". I want that icon.

Comment: use the camera button as a button to do what exactly? because if it's related to camera stuff i don't think there is a problem but if it does something completely different ....

Comment: yes it will do the camera stuff only. Should I use it's image as a UIButton?

Comment: To be more clear, I want to use that small camera graphic outside the UIToolbar.

Comment: @Dancreek forgot to tag you in the last comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a custom graphic which we owned to avoid any possibility of legal issues or app rejection.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [UIKit Artwork Extractor](https://github.com/0xced/UIKit-Artwork-Extractor) project to get internal iOS images from simulator, but I'm not sure if it's legal to use these images.

There are some examples:

[image]

[image]

PS:
You also can get a third-party icon for your needs, e.g. from http://www.glyphish.com/

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera` from [`UIBarButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It is a `UIBarButtonItem`, not a `UIButton`, but it is the real deal.